# How do I push pages onto the ion-nav element in Ionic using Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to use an ion-nav element to imitate a UINavigationController in iOS. The example found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav) only provides an example in Javascript and not in Angular. I don't know how to programmatically push pages onto the ion-nav element on my page. I've tried using ViewChild to access the ion-nav on my HTML page. Is this the correct way I should do it?

home.page.html

```
<ion-nav #nav [root]="rootPage">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
           App
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-button (click)="go()" expand="block">Start</ion-button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-nav>
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular/dist/providers/nav-controller';
import { InspectionMenuPage } from 'src/app/inspection-menu/inspection-menu.page';
import { IonNav } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('nav', {static: false}) nav: IonNav;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  go(){
    this.nav.push(InspectionMenuPage);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey, does it works?

Comment: so does it give you an error? looks legit

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of Ionic you're using. For version three and earlier versions you may use ion-nav. nav.push() navigates to the next page just as you've implemented it.
For version 4, there are different options. You could use NavController or Angular router.

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/route');
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

Comment: Yes I know I can use Angular Router but the documentation states that "Nav is a standalone component for loading arbitrary components and pushing new components on to the stack.

Unlike Router Outlet, Nav is not tied to a particular router." So I don't think I will be using Angular router to make nav changes. I want to do this using only ion-nav and not router outlet so I won't affect my app's url. But I don't know how to programmatically access the ion-nav API through Angular. Should I query the DOM for my ion-nav element and then use that? I'm using the latest version of Ionic v4.11.15

Comment: You could check this out..https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-looking-for-example-of-ion-nav-together-with-angular-routing/155559